# Limits of Multivariable CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How can I show that $\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} F_X(x)=0$?

Here's my approach so far:

$\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} F_X(x)=\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i}P(\bigcap^n_{i=1}(X_i\leq x_i))=\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} (1-P(\bigcup^n_{i=1}(X_i> x_i)))$
$=1-\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} P(\bigcup^n_{i=1}(X_i> x_i))=1-\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} \sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i> x_i)$
$=1-\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} \sum_{i=1}^n (1-P(X_i\leq x_i))$
$=1-n+\lim_{x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i} \sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i\leq x_i)$

Comment: What does ${x_i\rightarrow-\infty,\exists i}$ mean?

Comment: For any $x_i$ that goes to negative infinity

Comment: $F_X(x)\leq P(X_i \leq x_i) $ for all $i$ and $P(X_i \leq x_i)  \to 0$.